# how to control wpf listview checkbox style triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

What I'm wanting to do it make it so when users click on the 'checkbox' it toggles the styling so it appears as below. As you can see in the image below it changes from a gray heart to a red heart. All the bindings and vectors are in the code below. I'm just not sure on how to style the checkbox using my custom paths, and setting up the styling triggers. Hopefully someone can help me out.

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Print" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="trvFamilies" Grid.Row="1">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Family}" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Members.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:FamilyMember}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">
                            <Path SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Uniform" Width="12" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M0.5,0.5L10.5,0.5 15.25,5.75 15.25,20.5 0.5,20.5z">
                            </Path>
                            <Path SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Width="14" Fill="Red" Data="M4.833,2.16655086864422C4.833,3.36307577915264 3.66700013383223,4.24925064372868 2.6665,4.833 1.75033338617037,4.16590547819802 0.5,3.36307577915264 0.5,2.16655086864422 0.5,0.970025958135794 2.25033340729955,0.748849667983149 2.6665,2.16665418486839 3.08366677584818,0.832053199886277 4.833,0.970025958135794 4.833,2.16655086864422z">
                                <Path.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="2" />
                                </Path.Effect>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                        <CheckBox Margin="0,0,10,4" IsChecked="{Binding Favorite}"></CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" (" Foreground="Green" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Foreground="Green" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" years)" Foreground="Green" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```